# Filtering appointments not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office-interop, office-automation

In my test C# application using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.  I'm trying to receive only calendar events for the specified date.  The filter below equals:

```
[Start] >= '11/13/2022 00:00:00 AM' AND [END] <= '11/14/2022 11:59:59 PM'
```

But I'm running into two issues.  Sort doesn't seem to work, and the second problem is pulling appointments on future dates and skipping the appointments earlier in the morning.

[image]

```
...
DateTime dtFrom = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 11, 14);            
DateTime dtTo = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 11, 14);

Recipient teamMember = _app.Session.CreateRecipient("persons_email_address");
teamMember.Resolve();
if (teamMember.Resolved)
{
    MAPIFolder sharedCalendar = _app.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(teamMember, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
    if (sharedCalendar.DefaultMessageClass != "IPM.Appointment" || teamMember.DisplayType != 0)
    {
        return; //Calendar not shared.
    }

    var sdf = dtFrom.ToString("MM/dd/yyy") + " 00:00:00 AM";
    var sdt = dtTo.ToString("MM/dd/yyy") + " 11:59:59 PM";
    string restrictCriteria = $"[Start] >= '{sdf}' AND [END] <= '{sdt}'";

    Items items = sharedCalendar.Items;
    items.Sort("[Start]");
    items.IncludeRecurrences = true;
    var results = items.Restrict(restrictCriteria);
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= results.Count; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            AppointmentItem item = sharedCalendar.Items[i];
            Console.WriteLine("Item: {0}", i.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}", item.Subject);
            Console.WriteLine("Start: {0}", item.Start);
            //Console.WriteLine("Start: {0}", item.SenderName);
            Console.WriteLine("End: {0}", item.End);
            Console.WriteLine("Categories: {0}", item.Categories);
        }
        catch (System.Exception err)
        {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the condition (less than `Start` and greater than `End`) and format dates according to Outlook requirements. The following code works like a charm on my machine:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
// ...
private void RestrictCalendarItems(Outlook.MAPIFolder folder)
{
    DateTime dtEnd = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month,
                                  DateTime.Now.Day, 23, 59, 00, 00);
    string restrictCriteria = "[Start]<=\"" + dtEnd.ToString("g") + "\"" +
                              " AND [End]>=\"" + DateTime.Now.ToString("g") + "\"";
    StringBuilder strBuilder = null;
    Outlook.Items folderItems = null;
    Outlook.Items resultItems = null;
    Outlook._AppointmentItem appItem = null;
    int counter = default(int);
    object item = null;
    try
    {
        strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        folderItems = folder.Items;
        folderItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;
        folderItems.Sort("[Start]");
        resultItems = folderItems.Restrict(restrictCriteria);
        item = resultItems.GetFirst();
        do
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                if (item is Outlook._AppointmentItem)
                {
                    counter++;
                    appItem = item as Outlook._AppointmentItem;
                    strBuilder.AppendLine("#" + counter.ToString() +
                                          "\tStart: " + appItem.Start.ToString() +
                                          "\tSubject: " + appItem.Subject +
                                          "\tLocation: " + appItem.Location);
                }
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
                item = resultItems.GetNext();
            }
        }
        while (item != null);
        if (strBuilder.Length > 0)
            Debug.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString());
        else
            Debug.WriteLine("There is no match in the "
                             + folder.Name + " folder.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (folderItems != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderItems);
        if (resultItems != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(resultItems);
    }
}
```

You may check out the article which I wrote for the technical blog - [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/).